# Extended method on sequence doesn't throw exception unless I use ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, nunit

I am studying extended methods right now and I built one that works on portions of a sequence. If the passed dimension of the portion is not strictly positive it should throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException but in my nunit tests I managed to make it throw the exception only by calling ToList() on the result of the function.
Here is my code:

```
    public static class ExClass {
        public static IEnumerable<T> SplitAndReverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int size) {
            // Check if sequence is null
            if (size <= 0)
               throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size can only be a positive number");
            // Do something
            }
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass {

        [TestCase(0)]
        public void Test2(int range)
        {
            Assert.That(() => Enumerable.Range(1,10).SplitAndReverse(range).ToList(), Throws.TypeOf<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>());
        }
    }
```

I also tried to remove the ToList() method and save the result in a var. The values in that var are in this screenshot but I don't undestand it very well. In the last line it seems that an ArgumentOutOfRangeException was thrown by Items (why and why by Items?). In the second last row it's telling that the type "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" is not a valid type (again, why?).

[image: While debugging the result of the method]

One last thing that may help to know is that without the ToList() method I can't manage to enter the method in debug mode while with it enters without problems. I have another test that passes only valid arguments to the function and from that test I can manage to enter the method (it also works as expected).

Comment: You probably use 'yield return' in your SplitAndReverse method.

Comment: yes, I did but from what @Nuf said it shouldn't matter right? the problem is that without ToList() my call to the method is just a query right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range(1,10).SplitAndReverse(range)` is just a query and without `.ToList()` there is nothing to run evaluation of the query (thats why debugger doesn't work, because without `ToList()`, `SplitAndReverse` is not executed). LINQ queries are lazyly evaluated and are executed only when you enumerate them with `foreach`, or you call one of the materialization methods such as `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, `Count()`, `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Note that without knowing actual code of SplitAndReverse (whether it contains yield statements) - you cannot make such claim.

Comment: @Evk: I can make such claim, based on behaviour described by OP - it is obvious, that `SplitAndReverse` is not *normal* extension method, but was transformed by C# compiler into lazyly evaluated state machine (and therefore must contain `yield` statement). I should have metioned it in my post. Sorry if I made any confusion about it and thank you for clarification in your post, you have my upvote.

Comment: Well I thought that too, until OPs comment which indicated that he now thinks all IEnumerable methods behave this way, so it can as well confuse others I think.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true that everything that returns `IEnumerable` is lazy evaluated. Consider this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SplitAndReverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int size)
{
    // Check if sequence is null
    if (size <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size can only be a positive number");
    // just return
    return sequence;            
}
```

It just returns back the same sequence and has no `yield return` statements. Now if you do:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).SplitAndReverse(-1)
```

Without `ToList` - it will enter SplitAndReverse and will throw an exception. And why wouldn't it? It's just a regular method.

Now when you use `yield return` - your method is converted by compiler to something different (state machine), and when you call such method - its body will not be immediately executed (lazy evaluation). Instead - body will be executed (in parts) only when you enumerate the result (for example by calling `ToList`, like in your case). Most default LINQ methods (`Where`, `Select` and so on) indeed use such lazy evaluation, but your own method might or might not do that.

Comment: Now it makes much more sense, thanks for taking the time to explain everything :)